# factors in python with one function

Tags: python, list, factors

is it possible to reduce the functions factors and factor_list into one single function?

```
from functools import reduce

def factors(x):
    return [i for i in range(1, x + 1) if x % i == 0]

def factor_list(my_list):
  return set(reduce(list.__add__, map(factors, my_list), []))

def test(a_list):
  for num in a_list:
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, (i for i in range(1, num + 1) if num % i == 0), []))

test1 = [2, 8, 5, 9, 10]

print(test(test1)) #does not work
print(factor_list(test1)) #works
```

The above test gives me the error :

```
return set(reduce(list.__add__, (i for i in range(1, num + 1) if num % i == 0), []))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

So I'm curious as to how I could go about fixing this? the 2 functions at the top work fine, I would just like to learn how to write my code more efficiently

Comment: What errors? Give a [mcve]. Also why do you want to reduce it to a single function? The abstraction level seems about right, what I'd be inclined to refactor is the use of `reduce` with `list.__add__`.

Comment: `set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(factors, my_list)))`.

Comment: `reduce(list.__add__, ` No, **don't do this**. This is a polynomial time algorithm when you could trivially use a linear time algorithm.

Comment: `set(i for x in a for i in range(1, x + 1) if x % i == 0)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks! list comprehension worked

Comment: @ekhumoro you should just use a set-comprehension here, `{i for x in a for i in range(1, x + 1) if x % i == 0}`